# Why does `import site` fail to load site-specific paths under python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python2's `import site` works correctly, but Python3's does not. Use case: uwsgi running as a specific user, so requires `no-site` in .ini file. Symptom of problem: ModuleNotFoundError attempting to import lxml, which is under /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.

```
jcomeau@bendergift:~$ python -S
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload']
>>> import site
>>> sys.path
['/home/jcomeau', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/jcomeau/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3']

>>> 
jcomeau@bendergift:~$ python3 -S
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload']
>>> import site
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected:

> `python -S`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html

For Python versions >= 3.3:

> Importing this module will append site-specific paths to the module search path and add a few builtins, **unless -S was used**. In that case, this module can be safely imported with no automatic modifications to the module search path or additions to the builtins.

For Python versions < 3.3:

> Changed in version 3.3: **Importing the module used to trigger paths manipulation even when using -S**.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to figure out if the `no-site` option in uwsgi means they invoke Python3 with `-S`.

Answer (score 0):

The fix, as [fuzzy drawings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13462702/fuzzy-drawings)'s link indicates, was to call `site.main()`:

```
if tuple(sys.version_info) >= (3, 3):
    site.main()
```